# How to solve this complex number equation $\frac{(1-i)^{15}}{(1+i)^{15}}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

how to solve this equation $\frac{(1-i)^{15}}{(1+i)^{15}}$ ?.

I know its answer is (i). I got it through GNU Octave but I am not able to understand how to deal with such huge powers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\frac{(1-i)^{15}}{(1+i)^{15}} = \left(\frac{1-i}{1+i}\right)^{15} \\
= \left(\frac{(1-i)(1-i)}{(1+i)(1-i)}\right)^{15}\\
= \left(\frac{-2i}{2}\right)^{15} \\
= (-1)^{15} i^{15} \\ 
= -(-i) \\
= i$$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $1 \pm i = \sqrt{2}\left(\cos \pi/4 \pm i\sin \pi/4\right)$

Answer (score 0):

Using Euler's formula - 
$$e^{i \theta}=cos(\theta) + i sin(\theta)$$
We get - 
$$(1-i)=\sqrt{2}e^{-i \frac{\pi}{4}}$$
and
$$(1+i)=\sqrt{2}e^{i \frac{\pi}{4}}$$
So, $$\frac{(1-i)^{15}}{(1+i)^{15}} = \frac{(\sqrt{2})^{15} e^{-i \frac{15 \pi}{4}}}{(\sqrt{2})^{15} e^{i \frac{15 \pi}{4}}}=e^{-i \frac{15 \pi}{2}}=cos(- \frac{15 \pi}{2})+i sin(- \frac{15 \pi}{2})=i$$

This method, though seems a bit tedious, is pretty straight-forward and will be applicable even if the exponents of the numerator and denominator are different.
This method is also widely applicable because every complex number $a+ib$ can be written as -
$$a+ib=\sqrt{a^{2} +b^{2}}  e^{i\phi}$$ 
where $\phi=tan^{-1}(\frac{b}{a})$